# Segmentation Fault 11 When Using File I/O C++

Tags: c++, xcode, segmentation-fault, codeblocks, exc-bad-access

I am having an issue with Code Blocks and Xcode on my Mac.  Every time I run the code on Code Blocks I receive Segmentation Fault 11 and when I try on Xcode I receive Thread 1: exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x0xffffffff0000000a).  However, if I run this code on a PC via Code Blocks it runs.  Does anybody know how to solve this so I can run the program on my Mac.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Book
{
 string isbn;
 string title;
 string author;
 double price;
 string seller;
};

int main()
{
  Book booklist[100];
  ifstream infile;
  ofstream outfile;

  //int numBooks = 0;
  int i=0;
  char dummy;

  outfile.open("readBooks.txt");
  infile.open("usedBooks.txt");

  if (infile.fail())
  {
     cout << "The file doesn't exist";
     exit(-1);
  }

 else
 {
    //for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        getline (infile, booklist[i].isbn);
        getline (infile, booklist[i].title);
        getline (infile, booklist[i].author);
        infile >> booklist[i].price;
        infile.get(dummy);
        getline (infile, booklist[i].seller);

        outfile << "ISBN: " << booklist[i].isbn << endl;
        outfile << "Title: " << booklist[i].title << endl;
        outfile << "Author: " << booklist[i].author << endl;
        outfile << "Price: " << booklist[i].price << endl;
        outfile << "Seller: " << booklist[i].seller << endl << endl;
        i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You do no checking to see if "i" >= 100.  We have no idea how many lines are in that file, so why isn't your while() condition a little more robust? `while (i < 100 && !infile.eof())`

Comment: I forgot to give you the sample input file:

013283071X
Absolute C++, 5th Edition
Walter Savitch
71.89

I tried making the while loop more robust but it still does not fix the problem.

Comment: There is currently 76 lines in the input file.

Answer (score 2):

Your following line is causing the problem

```
 while (!infile.eof())
```

As it depends on what is the size of the file, however your array size is fixed and(.i.e. 100 where you are storing the data).

You should use *std::vector* in your program as :

```
std::vector<Book> booklist;

 while(/*check about infile>>x instead of !infile.eof()*/) {
        Book tmp;
        getline (infile, tmp.isbn);
        getline (infile, tmp.title);
        getline (infile, tmp.author);
        infile >> tmp.price;
        infile.get(dummy);
        getline (infile, tmp.seller);

        outfile << "ISBN: " << tmp.isbn << endl;
        outfile << "Title: " << tmp.title << endl;
        outfile << "Author: " << tmp.author << endl;
        outfile << "Price: " << tmp.price << endl;
        outfile << "Seller: " << tmp.seller << endl << endl;
        //Add into the vector after filling the data into the 
        //struct Book instance tmp
        booklist.push_back(tmp);
    }
```

**EDIT**
Yes, I we should not check the *infile.eof()* as this is not reliable way to identify the end of file. Instead of this we should check *infile>>x*. For more information please refer ISOCPP FAQ link on this: http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istream-and-eof

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected it in my post and also mentioned the appropriate link about this information.

Comment: Better. The problem is not that `eof` is "not reliable"; it's that the check was being performed at entirely the wrong place in the code. By checking for EOF/failures _as_ we read, we remove that problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
Book booklist[100];
```

Using magic numbers is poor practice. Are you sure that `i` is always less than 100 later in your program? If not then your program may do strange things. You should use `std::vector<Book> booklist;` instead. You might also want to use vector's `at()` member function to avoid mistakes with indexing the array out of bounds.

```
//for (i=0; i<100; i++)
while (!infile.eof())
{
```

Using the `.eof()` check with C++ streams in loop conditions is [almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Instead you probably want:

```
// returns true of book is successfully read, false otherwise
bool read_book(std::istream &is, Book &book) {
  Book tmp;
  if (getline(is, tmp.isbn) &&
      getline(is, tmp.title) &&
      getline(is, tmp.author) &&
      is >> tmp.price)
  {
    is.get(dummy);
    if (getline(is, tmp.seller)) {
        book = tmp;                                        // book = std::move(tmp)
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Book> booklist;

  // ...

  Book book;
  while (read_book(infile, book)) {
    booklist.push_back(book);
  }

  // ...
}
```

You should always check the result of input operations, and checking `eof()` on C++ streams does not do the correct check.